# Existence of finite projective resolution

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, projective-module

The situation I'm considering is quite involved.
All rings are noetherian commutative with $1$. All modules are finitely generated.

First of all we fix a non reduced local ring $A$ where all zero divisors are nilpotent element. Let $A^\prime$ be a quotient of $A$ by a principal ideal $t$, where $t$ is not a zero divisor in $A$.

Let $M$ be an $A$-module and suppose that one has a presentation of $M$ given by an exact sequence
$$ 0\to N'\to N\xrightarrow{\cdot(h)} N \to M\to 0$$
of $A$-modules, where the middle arrow is the multiplication by an element $h\in A$ that is a zero divisor of $N$ (I'm just saying that I don't want to assume $N'=\ker (\cdot h)$ to be $0$).

Assume the following extra conditions:
 a) $N$ is an $A'$-module of finite projective dimension. b) $N'$ is an $A'$-module.

**Questions:**

1) is it true that $N'$ has finite projective dimension as $A'$-module?

2)  is it true that $M$ is an $A'$-module of finite projective dimension?

3) can we deduce the existence of finite projective resolutions for the above objects as $A$-modules?

In case the questions do have negative answers, in which way one can add assumptions on the objects so that things do magically become true?

**EDIT:** I realized that I can actually ask a more precise question. I keep the previous notation, but I write specific examples for the modules:

$$M=A/(t - x^b) $$ for $x$ nilpotent (say with $x^m=0$ and $x^n\neq 0$ for $n<m$ and $b<m$).

$$N = A/(t^a-x^{ab}) = A/(t^a)$$ for some $a$ with $ab>m$.
Finally, I can take for $h$ an element of $A$ such that $h(t-x^b) = (t^a-x^{ab})$.

So I keep the general questions, but I'm curious to see an answer also in this specific case.

Comment: Apologies for an off-topic comment, but could I ask whether you managed to get an electronic copy of Artin's notes (http://mathoverflow.net/q/48943/1916)?

Comment: Actually I have a photocopied version of Artin's notes, that I photocopied from a photocopied version that my advisor had, that followed at that time the course at the MIT ... :)